# MYSQL - Order by multiple integer fields added together

Tags: mysql

I have 2 column (`column1` and `column2`) and I want to select all rows ordered by these 2 columns combined (added together, column1 + column2). Both columns are int values.

How would I do something like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table ORDER BY column1 + column2 DESC;
```

Example:

```
----------------------------
| ID | Column 1 | Column 2 |
----------------------------
| 1  | 70       | 20       |
----------------------------
| 2  | 10       | 40       |
----------------------------
| 3  | 30       | 50       |
----------------------------
```

Ordered output:

1. Row #1
2. Row #3
3. Row #2

Comment: Did you try that? It is exactly correct.

Comment: I did, but got a syntax error which I immediately asccosiated with this, but apparently it was something else - my bad.

Comment: @XLordalX  please check this  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/179c3f/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got it right. Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0837c4/1) that shows it in action.

I've added a second way of querying the table to make it more obvious that the results are returned in the correct order. For this simple example it isn't needed but it's a good way to "debug" your queries, add calculated values to the **select** portion and initially skip the **order by** to eliminate errors.

```
select id, one, two, one + two as sum from ints order by one + two desc;

select id, one, two, one + two as sum from ints order by sum desc;
```